# Headless Chrome: Run a webpage from command line without launching it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, phantomjs, headless-browser

I have a webpage that uses D3, [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) and [gif.js](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/) to generate GIFs of time-lapse maps. The page generates 3,000 gifs, one at a time. The page is not meant for public consumption.

While it works pretty well to just open this page and download the GIFs, it tends to be asking a lot of the browser. So I'm curious if there's a way to run a page headlessly from the command-line without actually opening it, but running the full app to render the page.

Why not just use Phantom from Node, you might ask? For starters, Phantom is hard! But more importantly, I've never had complete success using Phantom or any other client-side browser engine, like jsdom, to completely render SVGs exactly right.

So my question is basically whether it's possible to use Chrome instead of Phantom and launch a page from the command line that executes the page as if it was merely opened in the browser but without actually opening the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [electron](https://electron.atom.io/). The advantage would be you could very easily save your generated gifs, something you can't do with Chrome unless you also run a server.

Otherwise there are some [docs for headless chrome here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)